# Iron-list not update after element property changed

Tags: polymer-1.0

I'm having problems re-rendering an iron-list after changing an item property.

I need iron-list to re-render to apply new classes just like it does when i push or splice items.

Already tried almost everything(notifyPath, resize, _update, ...) but still doesn't make it work.

Please help :)

Below you can find an jsfiddle to ilustrate:

work OK:

```
this.set('words.'+i+'.checked', true);
```

NOT work:

```
this.notifyPath('words.'+i+'.checked');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s6f029j3/23/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your jsfiddle and made some changes. Try it now and see if this is what you were looking to do.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6f029j3/25/)

I made changes to the function on the paper-list to have it see if it had been checked there, rather than in the actual function.

```
<iron-list id="list" items="{{words}}">
        <template>
            <paper-item class$='[[_computedClass(item.checked)]]'>
              <div>Item: [[item.name]] checked: [[item.checked]]</div>
            </paper-item>
        </template>
    </iron-list>
```

and in the function, here's what I did:

```
_computedClass: function(e) {
            //WHY IT DOES NOT RE-RENDER AFTER CLICK????
        return (e) ? 'stuff_checked' : 'stuff_notchecked';
    },
```

By just removing the `.checked` it now works as intended.

Comment: Omg... can't believe it was so obvious. You save my day (and probably my job :)) 

THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked, don't forget to mark the answer so when someone else comes along they can get help too!